# Display videos from model in template - Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, video-streaming

Novice here. Trying to make web app that creates a video (with moviepy) and plays it in the browser. It should work something like this [app](https://www.incognitube.com/) but when user clicks 
button a video is created and displays.

I have a model with FileField where I upload videos which works fine. I set this up with a form but don't use it as I upload the videos with moviepy/python script.

Now I am trying to display the uploaded videos in the browser and am a little lost. Would be grateful for any guidance on how to go about this.

So far I've been trying variations on the below:

```
views.py

def video_upload_detail_page(request):
    obj = VideoUpload.objects.get(id=16)
    template_name = 'video_upload_detail.html'
    context = {'videofile': obj.videofile}
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

```
.html

{% load static %}

<br><br>
<video width='400' controls>
<source src="{{ object.videofile.url }}" type='video/mp4'>
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
<br><br>
```

and this is for the uploading:

```
models.py

from django.db import models

class VideoUpload(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField(max_length=500)
    videofile= models.FileField(upload_to='videos/', null=True)
```

```
forms.py (I don't actually use this as the videos are uploaded via python script)

from django import forms
from .models import VideoUpload

class VideoForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = VideoUpload
        #fields = ["name", "videofile"]
        fields = ["videofile"]
```

Comment: Why do you have source and src in your html? Also can you elaborate on what exactly is going wrong? What do you see in your browser, or what error do you get?

Comment: Source src relates to video - https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp. I was seeing only the video player in the browser with no video coming through.

Answer (score 0):

I tweaked the html like this `<source src= "{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ object.videofile }}" type='video/mp4'>` and the video now shows in the player.